# How to mock a protected variable in an abstract class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, abstract-class

Edit2: I was just blind and didn't see that the logger is initialized like

```
this.logger = authotrization.getLogger();
```

in constructor like all the others, overwork I guess, authorization is passed as parameter so now it is easy, this post is inrelevant now, thank you all for your time

Edit: so I edit my question a bit so it is clear what I am trying to do, hope now it is in stackoverflow standards, I have been in a hurry, my apologies

The following test results in a `NullPointerException`. Is it possible to avoid this, e.g. by mocking the protected `logger`?

```
abstract public class SomeClass {

    protected Legs legs;
    protected Logger logger;

    public SomeClass(String name, Cat cat) {
        this.legs = cat.getLegs();
        logger.info("Creating new {}", name);
    }

}
```

There are more variables inside the class and more parameters inside the constructor that are assigning some values to the variables but they don't affect the logger in any way so I didn't mention them.

here is my test class simplified:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class SomeClassTest {

    private ClassThatExtendsSomeClass classThatExtends;
    @Mock
    private Cat cat;
    @Mock
    private Logger logger;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
       mock(Cat.class)
       doReturn(new Legs()).when(cat).getLegs();
       mock(Logger.class)
       doNothing().when(logger).info(anyString(), anyObject());
   }

   @Test
   public void test() {
      classThatExtends = new ClassThatExtendsSomeClass("Hello World", cat);
      //it always fails here on the logger line in SomeClass
   }
}
```

Mocking the cat works because it is passed as parameter and the program knows that which cat I want to mock, but with logger it doesn't because I can't pass it as parameter and it is not @Inject and I don't know how to let mock knows that I want this logger to do nothing

I would rename 'SomeClass' rather to 'SomeAbstractClass' or something like that so it is more clear but there is already one answer and it would ruin it again sorry for the bad question I would rather discuss it in live chat but I can't access it.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. You see ... actually we can "not tell it gives NPE". Because you just dropped a tiny bit of production code, without your test code, or anything else. And of course, this here gives an NPE, because `logger` isn't initialised anywhere here. So, sorry: but we have no idea what you exactly you tried, thus nobody here will be able to help you.

Comment: I'd expect it to throw NPEs even without any mocking frameworks' involvement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a mocked `logger` in the constructor, you it requires two steps:

1. Create the mock in your test code.
2. Pass it to your production code, e.g. as a constructor parameter.

A sample test could look like this:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

public class SomeClassTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldNotRequireLogger() {
        Logger logger = mock(Logger.class);
        String name = "name";

        SomeClass someClass = new SomeTestClass(logger, name);

        assertNotNull(someClass.logger);
    }

    public class SomeTestClass extends SomeClass {

        SomeTestClass(Logger logger, String name) {
            super(logger, name);
        }

    }

}
```

---

Another possibility to avoid the `NullPointerException` is to pre-initialize the logger. However, whis way it will print logs during your test (which can be helpful):

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public abstract class SomeClass {

    protected static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeClass.class);

    public SomeClass(String name) {
        LOGGER.info("Creating new {}", name);
    }

}
```

---

*Finally, though this is clearly opinion-based and depending on the use-case, one might argue*: A constructor is not a logger, thus it should only *construct* an object, not print *log* messages. Thus, you could think about placing the `logger` call not inside the constructor, rather somewhere else.

Comment: In your example `logger` is not used (while `LOGGER` is), so there is no point of mocking it.

Comment: You're right, I've updated the example. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: +1 On logger not belonging in the constructor. I would say it doesn't belong in production code at all, including tests. Useless noise if tests are written well.